# How to destroy Swiper slider for VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, swiper.js

I need to destroy Swiper slider.

This code initializes the slider

```
<script>
  import { swiper, swiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper';

  export default {
    components: {
      swiper,
      swiperSlide,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        swiperOption: {
          autoplay: false,
          spaceBetween: 20,
          pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
          paginationClickable: true,
        },
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

How can I destroy slider if window width have changed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `eventListner` on `resize` like following and `destroySwiper` can be method which will take care of your logic on how to destroy swiper slider:

```
ready: function () {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.destroySwiper)
},
beforeDestroy: function () {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.destroySwiper)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but swiper have method destroy and i need to call this.
For example i try to
mounted() {
      this.$children[0].destroy();
    },
But method destroy is undefined or not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ref to your template first, then access the swiper instance on that ref to destroy

```
this.$refs[yourRef].$swiper.destroy()
```

See https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-destroy